# how to use more than ten filters in conditions of list view

Tags: custom-list

Can we create more than ten filters in list . SharePoint 2010 is providing only 10 filters OOTB and in my scenario i am having 35 filters how can i make it with. can we do it with JQuery ?[image]

Comment: Not tried. Open the view page in SharePoint Designer and try updating the CAML query.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JQuery on the list view will not be an option, because list data is queried from the server and usually is returned in pages. But you have several options:

**1. Simplify your filter query with calculated fields**. When you have complex queries it is good practice to create calculated columns with formula which has some boolean logic of the view and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` results, and then you can create views using these calculated column(s). This technique is highly recommended because can help you to strongly simplify your queries and improve performance.

**2. Create/modify a view programatically.** You should write your own CAML query and create a new view or  modify query part of an existing view if you have one already. There are some tools that can help you to write and test CAML query, like [CamlDesigner](http://www.camldesigner.com/). To modify/create a view you also have several options:

1. **Server Side code.** If you can use server side code it would be easiest to use PowerShell script (or C# code) and set the [SPView.Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.query.aspx)
2. **Client Side code.** You can also modify/create a view using CSOM or JSOM. `SP.View` object has a property [SP.View.viewQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247163.aspx)

Keep in mind if you create such a complex view in programatically you will not be able to modify it using UI.

**3. Use Search.** If you have such a complex query on the list and it has large set of data, you should consider using Search query to have better performance.